# Loading a Resource Assembly but without "locking" the file

Tags: c#, file, resourcedictionary, .net-assembly

I got a problem loading my assembly containing a resource xaml.
The problem is I am not allowed to "lock" the file, because an update may replace it later.

First I loaded it like this:

```
Uri uriProperties;
ResourceDictionary xResources;
uriProperties = new Uri("/xResources;component/xResources.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
xResources = Application.LoadComponent(uriProperties) as ResourceDictionary;
```

That worked fine. File is not locked.

Now I got another problem I had to put it into an other assembly. Loading it with the relative Uri does not work anymore, I have a full path now.

I tried:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(xPath + @"/xResources.dll");
xResources = new ResourceDictionary();
xResources.Source = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/xResources;component/xResources.xaml");
```

also works in the application. But it locks the file.

How do I load the assembly and get my resourcedictionary with using a full path but without locking the file?

Would be nice if there was a solution without using shadow copying or changing content paths etc...

Comment: Use the tag ".net-assembly", please. The tag "assembly" is for questions about assembly language programming.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but it's worth the shot:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("assemblypath");
var assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
```